# React Native Fetch data from api issue

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to fetch data and access it later from an api that involves token authorization. The token will be generating in other places. this is the current fetch method and the error I have. Please help, been stuck here for days.

```js
async getUserToken() {
        const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData")
        let data = JSON.parse(userData as string);
        let dataString = data._W.token as string
        return dataString
    }
    
    //fetch file from api here
    async componentDidMount(){

        try {
        const response = await fetch(SOME_RANDOM_API), {
          
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Token' + 
             await this.getUserToken(),
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            document: this.state.document,
            name: this.state.name,
            size: this.state.size,
            file_type: this.state.file_type,
            uploaded: this.state.uploaded,
          })
        })
       
         const responseJson = await response.json();
          
        console.log(responseJson)
        
        // console.log("response is"+ responseJson)
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
        console.log("response 2 is"+ responseJson)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error is"+ error);
      }
    }
```

error here

```
Object {
  "detail": "Unsupported media type \"application/json\" in request.",
}
error isTypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.dataSource.map...')

TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.dataSource.map...')
```

Comment: Is `state.document` a file? If it does, what type of file (base64?).

Comment: It is not a file, it is a category on that API json file. Just like the name, size, and so on.

Comment: i think eeror is occuring from a diff place. where ia the datasource.map is getting called..